# Como liberar toda memória alocada por um objeto - Delphi

Tags: delphi, gerenciamento-de-memória, sistema-operacional

Qual a melhor forma de de liberar toda memória alocada pela criação de um objeto para o S.O.

Não vamos considerar:

```
Objeto.Free;
Objeto := Nil;
Sysutils.FreeAndNil(Objeto);
```

Teria mais formas de se liberar a memória para o S.O.?

Comment: Sua pergunta é meramente educativa? Porque não podemos considerar os métodos mencionados?

Comment: usar apenas `Objeto := Nil;` não estará liberando a memória, apenas faz com que a variável não aponte mais para o objeto, o objeto ainda estará na memória e pra piorar você não tem mais um ponteiro para ela, então será impossível liberar a memória ocupada por esse objeto, isso é o que chamamos de vazamento de memória

Comment: Esta pergunta carece de explicação. O autor excluiu possíveis respostas na própria pergunta mas não deu a motivação. Não mostra assim aplicação da resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Aproveitando a resposta do Math, se vc simplesmente setar nil para o objeto ele ainda está alocado, mas vc está desassociando o ponteiro da variável da área de memória ocupada pelo objeto.

Quando vc chama o método

```
Objeto.Free
```

vc está fazendo a liberação deste objeto da memória

a diferença entre os métodos .Free e FreeAndNil é que o free and nil após liberar o objeto seta o valor nil para a variável.

O uso do FreeAndNil é mais comum para evitar erros onde você após liberar um objeto deseja validar se o objeto possui informações:

```
Objeto := TObject.Create;
Objeto.Free;
if Assigned(Objeto) then
  ShowMessage('Vai entrar aqui.');
```

Em outro caso:

```
Objeto := TObject.Create;
FreeAndNil(Objeto);
if Assigned(Objeto) then
  ShowMessage('NÃO vai entrar aqui.');
```

sendo assim, a resposta para sua pergunta, tanto o .Free quanto o FreeAndNil liberar todo o objeto e a questão entre usar o Free e o FreeAndNil se baseia mais em boas práticas

Comment: Mas a pergunta é sobre **outros métodos** de fazê-lo. Ele diz "Teria **mais** formas de se liberar a memória(...)?"

Comment: @EMBarbosa Sim, mas como a pergunta do título era _Como liberar toda memória alocada por um objeto_ e o fato de que `Objeto := nil` não libera a memória (exceto em caso de interfaces com contagem de referencia chegando a 0) achei q cabia a explicação.

Comment: Mas continua não sendo resposta à pergunta. Então deveria ter sido postado como comentário, por exemplo. A sua explicação é excelente. Só que não é uma resposta. :(

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte função que libera a memoria e zera o objeto, que seria a seguinte função:

```delphi
procedure FreeMemAndNil(var ptr; size: Integer = -1);
var
  p: Pointer;
begin
  p := Pointer(ptr);
  if p <> nil then
  begin
    if size > -1 then
      FreeMem(p, size)
    else
      FreeMem(p);
    Pointer(ptr) := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Ou simplesmente utilizar a função `FreeMem(pointer,size);`

## [Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3461375/2319589)

Comment: Se FreeMem destrói o objeto, dá para instanciar um objeto com o AllocMem? AllocMem pode ser usado para instanciar uma outra referência de um tipo record, por exemplo, qual a diferença entre todos esses casos?

Answer (score 1):

A documentação da linguagem explica que a maneira correta de liberar a memória ocupada por uma instância de classe é a invocação do [`destructor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.TObject.Destroy) desta classe.

No entanto, por questões de boas práticas, deve-se sempre usar os métodos `Free` ou `FreeAndNil` (conforme já explicado em outras respostas) e não invocar o método `Destroy` diretamente, ainda que isso seja de fato possível.

Após a execução do código do `destructor`, o método [`FreeInstance`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.TObject.FreeInstance) é invocado para que o gerenciador de memória do Delphi para devolver  este o bloco de memória que era ocupado pela instância.

No entanto, isso **não quer dizer que a memória será retornada para o sistema operacional**, de forma geral a mesma ficará disponível em uma lista encadeada de blocos de memória livre para ser novamente aproveitada sem que seja necessário alocar novamente memória do sistema (processo dispendioso).

O bloco de memória somente é de fato liberado para o sistema operacional quando corresponde a um bloco de memória do final do *heap* (área de memória de alocação dinâmica). Neste caso o gerenciador de memória procurará **encolher** o *heap*, liberando todos os blocos contíguos do fim para o começo.

O processo é este por que não é possível liberar blocos de memória do meio do *heap*, deixando lacunas no mesmo. O *heap* precisa ser contíguo.